# C# Change audio output device (not default)

Tags: c#

I've been looking all over the internet and did not found a solution for this yet.

Basically lets say i want to make some music program, then of course I want to make the output device changeable.
Important is it shall not set the default audio device.

Thanks!

Comment: Ever looked at [AudioSwitch](https://code.google.com/p/audioswitch/source/browse/trunk)? It's open source and probably contains the code you need. However this changes the windows's default audio. if you want to select an audio output device you should at least say which libraries you use for audio output as each has different documentation. There is also [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an audio library, or api, that has this functionality (most do). Libraries such as 
[FMOD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fmodnet/) or [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/). Though you might want to google for yourself to find one that suits your needs.

This library determines what output it uses for playing its audio, some can even use multiple outputs at the same time.